# How to pass and retrieve multiple parameters in lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'm currently developing a REST API using the serverless framework with python and dynamoDB. I would like to know how I can pass and retrieve parameters in my lambda function. My configuration on `serverless.xml` looks like:

```
getNearestConvenios:
  handler: src/controllers/convenio_controller.get_nearest_convenios
  events:
    - http:
        path: convenios/nearest
        method: get
        cors: True
        request:
          template:
            application/json: '{ "lat" : "$input.params(''lat'')",  "long" : "$input.params(''long'')"}'
```

and I'm trying to retrieve the parameters like this:

```
def get_nearest_convenios(event, context):
  try:
    parameters = event['pathParameters']
    convenios = service.get_nearest_convenios(parameters['lat'], parameters['long'])
    return http.ok(convenios)
  except Exception as ex:
    logger.warn("WARNING: Request id: {0}, Error: {1}, Info: {2}".format(context.aws_request_id, type(ex), ex.args))
    return http.bad_request(str(ex))
```

I followed the [Custom Request Templates](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#custom-request-templates) provided on the official documentation, but I had no success until now. Also, in CloudWatch the following error is being showed:

```non
    [WARNING]   2020-08-14T09:04:11.783Z    3c9222b2-4601-4460-ba7c-3cd89ba3b04b    WARNING: Request id: 3c9222b2-4601-4460-ba7c-3cd89ba3b04b, Error: <class 'TypeError'>, Info: ("'NoneType' object is not subscriptable",)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you haven't specified any integration type in your lambda, therefore it will use the default `lambda-proxy` integration type. In Lambda proxy integration, when a client submits an API request, API Gateway passes to the integrated Lambda function the raw request as-is. You cannot use mapping templates with `lambda-proxy` integration. If you would like to transform your request or response, you can choose lambda integration without proxy.

You are using an HTTP GET. Therefore you can pass the data as a query string or path parameters.

- Query string: you pass the data in the url for example http://api.example.com/Books?id=1. The query string parameters can be accessed inside the lambda as `event. queryStringParameters`
- Path Parameters: you can define a parameter in your serverless template as below. then you can access the path parameters inside the lambda like `event.pathParameters`

  ```
  getNearestConvenios:
  handler: src/controllers/convenio_controller.get_nearest_convenios/{parameter}
  events:
    - http:
        path: convenios/nearest
        method: get
        cors: True
  ```

Reference:
[Lambda Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! I removed the implementation of mapping templates and inside the "get_nearest_convenios" function I changed the key "pathParameters" to "queryStringParameters" and it worked just fine! :)